# I'm having some problems with a few images not loading but the rest are

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site and I am designing a landing page where you click on pictures and it will take you to a product page.

I have just hit a problem that I was asked to put a slider into the page above everything, I haven't yet started that and thought that i would upload the site for now to a test server to make sure everything is running OK.

Most of the page is but there are three images on one section (3/6) that just will not load. I've looked over the coding and cant seem to find any mistakes with the code.

Comment: share part of your code and css

Comment: How can anyone help if there's no demo/link...

Comment: the url to the images is probably wrong.

Comment: Or, it could be that the problem is between "is" and "but" in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You must provide some of your code referring to the images, then only someone can help you. Anyway there can be an issue that you were not providing the correct path for the image. Also, sometimes it happens issue with writing the format of the image in caps or small letter. It make work with image.gif but not with image.GIF for example. So, look into image property also and find the correct format.

Comment: sorry its my first time using this and i had a friends who was able to help me sort it. thank you anyway

Comment: most welcome... It would be more better if you explain what was the issue and what you did it with...

Comment: sure, it turns out that becuase im working on a temporary sever that the company have set up for me.  sometimes the images for some reason dont upload into my server but theirs and thats why i could get the images, becuase they wanst on my network.